# Are raring arm packages available someplace?

Tags: 13.04, upgrade

I neglected to update my ARM system from raring to saucy in time. Now I can't install update-manager-core; things are missing.

Is there a way to manually update sources.list to point to some sort of archive so that I can get the update to saucy?

Comment: @Tim, no OP's problem is a bit more complicated. See [this Q](http://askubuntu.com/questions/509242/upgrading-raring-to-saucy-on-arm) and [this chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16330/discussion-between-bmargulies-and-muru) for background. I looked around and couldn't find archives for `armhf` in old-releases or elsewhere.

Comment: @muru okay, I have retracted the vote. It is OT tho isn't it?

Comment: @Tim He's trying to upgrade, after all. I think there's some precedent for upgrade-related questions being on topic.

Comment: This question is a duplicate. @muru knows what it's a duplicate of; he propose to close another question of mine to the correct target. The answer to this was the usual old-releases URL. After applying that, I ran into a much muckier problem with do-release-upgrade and arm for saucy that and I were unable to solve.

Comment: @bmargulies consider linking to the old question and chat and editing this question a bit so that others know this is a more problematic... er, problem.

Comment: The dup is http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release.

Comment: Does this question still apply? I'm not sure I understand if your issue was solved or not.

Comment: _this_ issue was solved by switching to 'old-releases', in that I was able to install the updater package, for arm, once I switched to it. The subsequent issue in using the updater package, no, I've never found a solution to it.